# How to use multiple elements in one set of code for javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button1").click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop : $("#screen1").offset().top
    }, 800);
  });
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button2").click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop : $("#screen2").offset().top
    }, 800);
  });
})

...and so on
```

I wrote above code in javascript. If button is clicked, it scrolls to #screen position. However, I have several ".button"s and "#screen"s that basically has the same function. I don't want to repeat the same code so I've tried for in statement, but couldn't get it right. In what way can I avoid repeating codes in this situation?

Comment: Try to use function `each()`.

Answer (score 2):

Now, I cant see your HTML code, but my suggestion would be to add the event listener to a parent element to all the buttons and then add info about the button on the button itself. Here I'm using the attribute `data-screen` to hold info about the "screen".

**UPDATE**

I refined the jquery a bit. Using `on()` instead of `click()` so that I could remove the original `if` statement. When the event listener is on the parent element more buttons can be added dynamically and they will work as expected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#buttons").on("click", "button", function(e) {
    var screenid = $(e.target).attr('data-screen');
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(`#screen${screenid}`).offset().top;
    }, 800);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons">
  <button data-screen="1">Button 1</button>
  <button data-screen="2">Button 2</button>
  <button data-screen="3">Button 3</button>
</div>

<div>
  <div id="screen1"></div>
  <div id="screen2"></div>
  <div id="screen3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like the solution. I'd suggest to use `$("#buttons button")` (instead of the if statement) as a listener and `const screenid = $(this).attr('data-screen')` to get the id

Comment: @A_A thanks for the tips. I'm not into jquery. Not it is mush better.

Comment: You can use `.data('screen')` instead of `.attr('data-screen')`: https://api.jquery.com/data/
P.S. And `$(this)` instead of `$(e.target)`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the buttons & screens follow the naming convention `.button${number}` and `#screen${number}`, you can do this:

```js
const numberOfSections = 5;

$(document).ready(function() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfSections ; i++) {
    $(`.button${i}`).click(function() {
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop : $(`#screen${i}`).offset().top
      }, 800);
    });
  }
});
```